# ECS Task deployment problem in terraform config

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, fastapi

I'm currently going through a tutorial from testdriven.io.

I have followed the tutorial exactly and now I'm having an error that I don't know how to solve. I'm new to terraform so I have gone through the code and think I have found the problem but I don't have the answer.

error: **"STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem)"**
image: **aws-account-id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/talk-booking-dev:latest**

So in the tutorial I have created this ci-cd.yml file:

```
.service-talk-booking-docker-image:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/<your-gitlab-username>/talk-booking:cicd-docker
  stage: docker
  services:
    - docker:19.03.0-dind
  before_script:
    - cd services/talk_booking/
    - poetry export --without-hashes --with-credentials -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region <region-of-your-application> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region-of-your-application>.amazonaws.com
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG" .
    - docker push "$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG"

service-talk-booking-docker-image-development:
  extends: .service-talk-booking-docker-image
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: <your-ecr-url>:development-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
      - master
    changes:
      - services/talk_booking/**/*
```

which makes the docker image tag as your-ecr-url:development-$CI_COMMIT_SHA

But in the ecs_task.tf I have this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family                = "${var.environment_name}-app"
  container_definitions = <<EOF
[
    {
      "name": "talk-booking-app",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.talk-booking.repository_url}:latest",
      "cpu": 1000,
      "command": [
        "gunicorn",
        "--bind",
        "0.0.0.0:${var.container_port}",
        "web_app.main:app",
        "-k",
        "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
      ],
      "memory": 950,
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [
        {"name": "APP_ENVIRONMENT", "value": "${var.app_environment}"},
        {"name": "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "value": "${var.region}"}
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": ${var.container_port}
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.talk-booking-log-group.name}",
          "awslogs-region": "${var.region}",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_stream.talk-booking-log-stream.name}"
        }
      }
    }
]
EOF
```

Where the image tag is "${aws_ecr_repository.talk-booking.repository_url}:latest"

So I think the problem is that the ECS is trying to use wrong image tag because terraform is not pushing to ECR with the tag :latest but with the tag :development-$CI_COMMIT_SHA

How could I get the tag in ecs_task.tf be :development-$CI_COMMIT_SHA ?

Comment: Change `:latest` to `:development-${var.ci_commit_sha}` and define an input variable for `ci_commit_sha`.

Comment: Thanks! After some research I was able to do it. Found out also that when running one container in a task in ECS, for some reason it automatically applies the tag :latest to the image.